# Simple nuxt 3 transition only works for one page

Tags: transition, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I have my personal portfolio built in Nuxt 3, and I wanted to add simple page transitions. Although I followed all the instructions in the Nuxt 3 documentation, the transition ("fade") only works for my second page ("About").

This is my nuxt.config.js file:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: false,
  runtimeConfig: {
    vite: {
      css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
          scss: {
            additionalData: '@use "@/assets/_colors.scss" as *;'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    css: [
      '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css'
    ]
  },
  app: {
    head: {
      htmlAttrs: {
        lang: 'en'
      },
      charset: 'utf-8',
      link: [
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;500&display=swap', crossorigin: 'anonymous' }
      ]
    },
    pageTransition: {
      name: "fade",
      type: "transition"
    }
  }
})
```

The css for the transition is in my app.vue file:

```
<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
    <NuxtPage />
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
  .fade-enter-active,
  .fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
  }

  .fade-enter,
  .fade-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
  }
</style>
```

Finally, in each of my vue pages, I have added the following script:

```
<script>
  export default {
    transition: 'fade'
  };
</script>
```

The transition works only for the page I immediately navigate to, AFTER navigating to the About page first. I also tried adding `mode: 'out-in'` as per the Nuxt3 documentation and that caused my pages to display nothing. Please help me out and point me in the right direction to fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

One solution it's in nuxt 3 page transitions works from different way.

1 steps it's remove the pageTransition configuration from the app object in nuxt.config.js and put in tou app.vue, similar than that:

```
<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
    <NuxtTransition>
      <NuxtPage />
    </NuxtTransition>
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
  your css
</style>
```

Comment: Hi, is it just adding the `<NuxtTransition>`, or is there anything else I need to do? I tried adding just the `<NuxtTransition>` but it doesn't seem to solve the issue, but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: try this for using global in nuxt 3 add nuxt.config.js

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // ...
  globalOptions: {
    // ...
    pageTransition: {
      name: "fade",
      type: "transition"
    }
  }
}) 

e nos eu template 

<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
      <NuxtPage />
    </transition>

Comment: Now it's back to the initial problem state, where for some reason the transition only applies if I visit the "About" page first, and then navigate to any other page.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a bit of a weird solution while trying to solve another problem. Apparently when I added the following code,

```
definePageMeta({
  layout: 'default'
});
```

on each of my pages, the `transition` animation started working for all the pages.